# How to prove Thomsen's theorem?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[**Thomsen's theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomsen%27s_theorem) states that given a triangle ABC, choosing a point on AB (but not A or B) and doing the internal path parallel to AC till reaching BC, and then doing the path parallel to AB till reaching AC, and then doing the path parallel to BC till reaching AB, and then doing the path parallel to AC till reaching BC... and so on, one eventually returns to the initial point.

For visualization, you can check the image ([link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/Satz_von_Thomsen.svg/500px-Satz_von_Thomsen.svg.png)) from Wikimedia Commons for example:

[image]

I have no idea on how to prove this. Maybe it's something very elementary, but I don't see it.

Comment: I think I got it. It has something to do with the parallelograms formed and vectors.

Comment: Funny how just writing the question here and looking at the image gave me some idea... In the end the vectors sum amount to 0. Okay, I can sleep now!

Comment: I actually don't see it. Could you type up your thoughts as an answer?

Comment: Perhaps use the figure above and use $\sim$ of $\Delta$s. Start with $6$ points like above and show that with parallel conditions you get $\sim$s. Then show that the parallel paths imply $\sim$ triangles. You can then establish a bijection between the parallel triangles with appropriate conditions and parallel paths, that is, for each path you showed the configuration above is valid and one indeed returns to the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a preferred direction around the triangle, so that a given point separates a side into consistently-ordered "first" and "second" sub-segments. If a given $P_i$ separates a side of the triangle into "first" and "second" sub-segments with lengths in the ratio $1:k$, then $P_{i+1}$ separates the *next* edge into sub-segments with lengths in the ratio $k:1$.

We have, then, that the ratio flip-flops as the path bounces around a three-sided figure. Every *second* step of the process returns to the initial ratio, $1:k$, while every *third* step returns to the initial side.  Consequently, the process has "period" $6=2\cdot 3$ (or a divisor thereof), which is to say that points $P_{i}$ and $P_{i+6}$ must coincide.

**Note.** If $k=1$, then the ratios $1:k$ and $k:1$ match, making the "flip-flops" irrelevant, so that the process has "period" $3$; points $P_i$ and $P_{i+3}$ (and $P_{i+6}$) coincide. (In this special case, we recognize that the $P_i$ are the vertices of the midpoint triangle of $\triangle ABC$.) If $k\neq 1$, then the process has "period" exactly $6$.

Comment: Very beautiful solution! Thank you.